How to make a central hamburger push down content below it or at least fill width when open
I have created a responsive nav bar with content to left and hamburger central and shopping cart to right. All within defined nav bar space. How do I get hamburger - when open - to push down content below it or fill width without moving content to left and right [on nav]? Also how to have media queries show full nav menu at wider screen?


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #72848C;
}

html,
body {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "apparat", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  content: url("../images/icons/fontawesome-free-6.4.0-web/svgs/solid/heart.svg") url("../images/icons/shopping-bag_white_VFgreyDK.png")
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*header one*/


/*main nav bar*/

.header-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7c9d3;
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
}


/*main nav bar left side button*/

.header-main-left {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid #72848C;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #72848C;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  transition: .4s;
}

.mlist {
  border: 1px solid #72848C;
  background-color: white;
}

.mlist:hover {
  border: 1px solid #72848C;
  background-color: #d7e1e6;
  color: #72848C;
}


/*nav bar main menu*/

.header-main-nav {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header-main-nav ul {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header-main-nav li {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: .85em;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.header-main-nav li a {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #72848C;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header-main-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: 2px solid underline #72848C;
}

.header-main-nav li a:active {
  text-decoration: 2px solid underline #72848C;
}

.header-main-nav a:hover,
.header-main-nav .menu-btn:hover {
  text-decoration: underline 2px solid #72848C;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Mobile Menu*/

.menu {
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0px;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  transition: max-height .4s ease-out;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header-main-nav .menu-icon {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-main-nav .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: #72848C;
  display: block;
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 25px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .4s ease-out;
}

.header-main-nav .menu-icon .nav-icon:before,
.header-main-nav .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  background: #72848C;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.header-main-nav .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  top: 7px;
}

.header-main-nav .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  top: -7px;
}


/*menu bt hamburgern*/

.header-main-nav .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header-main-nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 340px;
}

.header-main-nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header-main-nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.header-main-nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0;
}


/*nav bar right hand icons*/

.header-main-right {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding-right: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.header-main-right-favourites {
  width: 23px;
  height: 22px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-image: url("../images/icons/heart3.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  align-self: center;
}

.header-main-right-shopping {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url("../images/icons/shopping-bag_white_VFgreyDK.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  align-self: center;
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vivienne Foley</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="CSS/index.css" title="Index" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://use.typekit.net/vkb0vvr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
    body,
    td,
    th
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/logo/favicon-vf.ico">
  <link href="CSS/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-main">
    <div class="header-main-left">
      <a href="contactform.html"><button class="btn mlist">CONTACT</button></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="header-main-nav">

      <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
      <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>

      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="porcelain.html">PORCELAIN</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="bronze.html">BRONZE</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="archive.html">ARCHIVE</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="publications.html">PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="press.html">PRESS</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="inspiration.html">INSPIRATION</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="header-main-right">
      <a>
        <div class="header-main-right-favourites"></div>
      </a>
      <a>
        <div class="header-main-right-shopping"></div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </header>

  <div class="col">
    <h1>VIVIENNE FOLEY</h1>
    <h2>PORCELAIN &amp; BRONZE</h2>

    <div class="vflogo"><img src="images/logo/VFlogo.png" alt="vflogo" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <main>
    <section class="container4">
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card-img">
          <a href="porcelain.html"><img src="images/home/DSC_1614._foliatepair_hero_LR.jpg" alt="foliatepair"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer"><a href="porcelain.html"><button>PORCELAIN</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card-img">
          <a href="bronze.html"><img src="images/bronzes/03_vf_Torc_LR3.jpg" alt="torc"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <a href="bronze.html">
            <button>BRONZE</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card-img">
          <a href="archive.html"><img src="images/home/hero_2010_42.jpg" alt="ong"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <a href="archive.html">
            <button>ARCHIVE</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer-container">

      <div class="social">
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/vivienne-foley-699ba82a/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/viviennefoleyporcelain/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=61556683737387" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      </div>

      <div class="footer-text">

        <p class="footer-text">
          All photography &copy; Vivienne Foley. Photography may not be reproduced without prior permission. Vivienne Foley asserts design &amp; intellectual property rights over all her work. &copy; All rights and images reserved.</p><br>
        <p class="footer-links">
          <a href="">Site Map</a>
          <a href="privacypolicy.html#terms">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
          <a href="privacypolicy.html#privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
          <a href="privacypolicy.html#disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>
          <a href="privacypolicy.html#copyright">Copyright</a>
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>Site by Moonmouse Creative Ltd.</p><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/55848d0aa2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>


</html>




Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
